# Edit CSV without EXCEL

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to edit a .CSV file by shifting the first column of data down 1 row. then taking the last value in the first column and move it to the top. Any idea how I can do this without using

```
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps use [`Import-Csv`](https://www.petri.com/powershell-import-csv-cmdlet-parse-comma-delimited-csv-text-file) to programmatically modify the column.

Comment: jspcal How could I do this? I am not familiar with import-csv

Comment: Check out that link it has some examples.

Comment: What is the purpose of shifting column 1 down and putting the bottom value on top of the column? Are you trying to do a sort?

Comment: jspcal I'm looking at the examples, but they don't seem to adjust the column and move them down a row.

Comment: @shadoe2020 This file contains keywords and I rotate the "keyword" in column one, by shifting it down 1 and putting the bottom to the top.

Comment: What does the rest of the csv look like? How many columns?

Comment: **Clothing Rental,Chicago Illinois,1,25** This is an example of how every line looks.

Comment: is there a header in the csv file or no header?

Comment: @shadoe2020 no there is no header.

Comment: I almost have a solution, just wanted to clarify... you only want the first column to shift down one? That doesn't extend to your other columns? Like If I move row 2 to row 3 for column 1, is that also supposed to happen in the other columns?

Comment: Did Theo's solution not work? I never posted mine because I assumed it was working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I wouldn't know why you want to rotate the values in one of the columns, here is how you can do that without the need for Excel.

From your comments, I gather the CSV file has no headers and contains only data rows.
Because of that, the following adds headers when importing the data.

Suppose your csv file looks like this:

> ```
> Clothing Rental,Chicago Illinois,1,25
> Clothing Purchase,Dallas Texas,2,35
> Clothing Free of Charge,Phoenix Arizona,3,45
> ```

Then the following should do what you want:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\yourdata.csv' -Header 'Stuff','City','Number','InStock'    # or add whatever headers you like
# get the first column as array of values
$column1 = $data.Stuff
# rotate the array values
switch ($column1.Count) {
    1 { Write-Host "Nothing to do here. There is only one row of data.."; break}
    2 { 
        # swap the values
        $data[0].Stuff,$data[1].Stuff = $data[1].Stuff,$data[0].Stuff
        break
    }
    default {
        $newColumn1 = @($column1[-1]; $column1[0..($column1.Count -2)])
        # re-write the first column in the data
        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $newColumn1.Count; $i++) {
            $data[$i].Stuff = $newColumn1[$i]
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$data

# output to new CSV file WITH headers
$data | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\your_rotated_data.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force

# output to new CSV file WITHOUT headers
$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path 'D:\your_rotated_data.csv' -Force
```

The output on screen after running this looks like

> ```
> Stuff                   City             Number InStock
> -----                   ----             ------ -------
> Clothing Free of Charge Chicago Illinois 1      25     
> Clothing Rental         Dallas Texas     2      35     
> Clothing Purchase       Phoenix Arizona  3      45
> ```

and you can see all values in the first column ("Stuff") have been rotated, i.e. the last value is now on top and the other values have moved down.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I adjusted it slightly to remove quotations.